# Why laravel unregister the loadClassLoader very closely after it register it in the autoload_real.php?

Tags: php, laravel, autoload

In the laravel autoload_real.php's `getLoader()` function, it register the `loadClassLoader` first, then it unregister it.

What does it really do, and the reason here?

```
public static function getLoader()
{
    if (null !== self::$loader) {
        return self::$loader;
    }

    require __DIR__ . '/platform_check.php';

    spl_autoload_register(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit5768790f6ab6e3848d5c50fd89cc28cc', 'loadClassLoader'), true, true);
    self::$loader = $loader = new \Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader(\dirname(\dirname(__FILE__)));
    spl_autoload_unregister(array('ComposerAutoloaderInit5768790f6ab6e3848d5c50fd89cc28cc', 'loadClassLoader'));
```

Comment: Well it seems to avoid unnecessary overhead in regular class loading scenarios which is why  it's registering and then unregistering the `loadClassLoader` function to ensure that it is only executed once during the Composer autoloader initialization process.